# Find and replace a part of a string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

I have an SQL query in a string and I want to replace a part of the string with a new value.

The part in the string I'm looking for is a : until it hits either a , or a ). The part it finds needs to be replaced by a question mark.

I've been working on this for a while but I can't seem to find a solution how to fix this.

Can anyone help me further?

Example String I want to get a part of:

```
"INSERT INTO ORDERS  ( ORDER_ID, CUSTNO, COMPANY_NAME, ITEM, AMOUNT1, AMOUNT2) &#xD;&#xA;VALUES ( :WS_ORDER_ID, :WS_ORDER_CUSTNO, :WS_ORDER_COMPANY_NAME, :WS_ITEM, :WS_AMOUNT1, :WS_AMOUNT2)"
```

So what I want the string to look like is:

```
"INSERT INTO ORDERS  ( ORDER_ID, CUSTNO, COMPANY_NAME, ITEM, AMOUNT1, AMOUNT2) &#xD;&#xA;VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

What i was trying to create:

```
public String Replace(String value, String firstValue, String lastValue, String replacementValue) {
      int firstLocation = value.IndexOf(firstValue);
      var lastLocation = value.IndexOf(lastValue);

      if (value.Contains(firstValue)) {
        String modifiedValue;
        modifiedValue = value.IndexOf(Convert.ToChar(firstLocation), lastLocation.ToString());
        String newValue = value.Replace(modifiedValue, replacementValue);
      }

      return newValue;
    }
```

Something like this but I can't figure it out.

And then I want to have a foreach loop that takes this method and replaces every :WORD, with a ?.

Best regards

Comment: So you want parameter names, like `:foo`, to be replaced by `?`, as long as they are followed by a comma or closing parentheses?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using this as a prepared statement? the `:PARAM_NAME` form is widely used as placeholder in prepared statements with SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method like this should do the trick if ':' is guaranteed to be unique as a token:

```
public string Replace(string text)
{
    string[] items = text.Split(':');
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.Append(items[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<items.Length;i++)
    {
        string item = items[i].TrimEnd();
        stringBuilder.Append("?" + item[item.Length - 1]);
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work for every occassion. When the parameter is not at the end of the query it just deletes the rest of the query lol.